# Нет данных в ListView который внутри ListFramgent

Tags: java, android, android-fragment, listview, android-asynctask

У меня есть 2 Фрагмента типа `ListFragment` , они внутри `TabLayout` -а.

```
private TabAdapter adapter;
private TabLayout tabLayout;
```

Проблема на втором фрагменте, я беру данные из сервера с помощью AsyncTask.
По завершению загрузки добавляю данные в List и в методе PostExecute инициализирую ArrayAdapter и передаю его в ListView,данные есть но ListView не появляется на экране.
Вот мой `ListFragment`

```
public class Tab2Fragment extends ListFragment  {
    Conf conf = new Conf();
    ArrayList<String> myData = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> imgUrl = new ArrayList<String>();
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_content_2,container,  false);
        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        new GetDataAsyncTask().execute();
    }
```

Сам AsyncTask

```
class GetDataAsyncTaskextends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        private ProgressDialog dialog;

        public void GetDataAsyncTask(){

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            dialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
            dialog.setMessage("загрузка...");
            dialog.setCancelable(false);
            dialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            //запрос на сервер**** 
            //заполняю List imgUrl;
           return null;
         }
         @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            if (dialog.isShowing()) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
            MyAdapter myListAdapter = new MyAdapter(getActivity(),R.layout.d_layout_item,imgUrl);
            getListView().setAdapter(myListAdapter);

        }
```

и мой ArrayAdapter

```
public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
        private Context mContext;
        private List list;
        public MyAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,List list) {
            super(context, textViewResourceId);
            mContext = context;
            this.list = list;
        }
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.d_layout_item, parent,
                    false);
            TextView catNameTextView = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.depfio);
            TextView za = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.dep_za);
            TextView protiv = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.dep_protiv);
            ImageView img = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.deImg);
            catNameTextView.setText(list.get(position)+"");
            Picasso.with(mContext).load(R.mipmap.pet_icon).into(img);
            return row;
        }
    }
```

в MainActivity я делаю так

```
adapter = new TabAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFragment(new Tab1Fragment(), "1-й Таб");//Выводятся(показываются) данные только в этом фрагменте 
        adapter.addFragment(new Tab2Fragment(), "2-й Таб");//вот этот пустой
        adapter.addFragment(new Tab3Fragment(), "3-й Таб");//эту еще не пробовал заполнять и показывать
```

Помогите пожалуйста если кто то раньше делал несколько фрагментов с ListView,застрял на этом моменте.Показать ListView на всех фрагментах

Comment: Попробуйте в MyAdapter добавить метод `getCount() return list.size(); `

Comment: @AlexanderChernin огромное вам спасибо.Сработало.